# What drastic changes would occur if an architect went to ancient times

Tags: science-fiction, alternate-history, empire-building

My character Ray was transported to the most fertile region of Africa about 569 B.C.

He was born in into a small farming family and learned about the history and evolution of farming because his father was fascinated with the subject later ray joined the army and served one tour in Iraq.

Ray completed College and became a world renowned architect he even received a few pointers from Zaha Hadid and Ghery after an accident he was bonded with nanites and sent to the past along with 1000 others.

he can't die because of the nanites the nanites also in enhances the languages Center of the brain to allow him to quickly learn languages. The nanites dont enhance much else except giving him physically the upper limits a human can achieve.

No matter what happens he won't be erased from existence and he is black that's why I didnt choose Europe because itd probably be weird if he was in Europe also he would allow the transatlantic slave trade because he believes if he doesn't he'll never exist but he'll try and stop colonialism in Africa.

What drastic changes would we see and would he be able to change how cities today look. The goal is for him to rule

Comment: What, in your opinion, was *"he most fertile region of Africa"* in the 6th century before the common era? Was it inhabited by civilised people? Do you understand that in the very very long time between the 6th century BCE and anything which can be characterized as "colonialism in Africa" *a lot* of things can happen?

Comment: East Africa I believe is the most fertile region. And I know there is a very long time the main aspect is he has future knowledge of farming techniques and architecture that's what's important the I only mentioned slavery to show that America will still exist because he will try and create it

Comment: It's a little nit-picky (and I mean no disrespect to any architects) but an architect is typically specialised in artistic design and project management rather than physical construction or the actual engineering of a building. The people who actually run the numbers, calculate the beams, and choose concrete mix ratios would be civil engineers.

Comment: What is "East" Africa? Egypt, Somalia and Ethiopia and in the eastern part of Africa and a large part of their territory is desertic. The eastern part of Africa is a very large territory... (Moreover, nobody has ever ruled over the entire eastern half of Africa; and, what's more important for such a story, nobody has ever even attempted to take over the entire eastern half of Africa.)

Comment: Frankly, if the world worked like your basic assumption: that a person from an advanced culture is innately superior to those in a technologically backward society, and could revolutionize it in a jiffy. Then it would only take a handful of Peace Corps workers to have modernized the whole African continent, last century. For Ray to survive in the past will be difficult enough by itself. To say nothing of changing it. It's too big a task for one man.

Comment: "most fertile region of Africa" - Nile delta? 569 B.C. looks like 26th dynasty.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### If Ray survives and prospers, it won't be because he's an architect.

Ray is a world-renowned *21st century* architect.  He is used to designing buildings using concrete rebar, steel, glass.  He's used to buildings that are straight when they're supposed to be and curved when they're not, because the available raw materials are manufactured to tight tolerances and have predictable and repeatable properties.  When designing buildings using these materials, Ray has access to digital databases of said properties, and computer drafting tools which as well as allowing him to draw quickly, process near-instantaneously the vast amount of number-crunching required to validate those properties against the requirements of the building.

When Ray first lands in 569BCE, the materials he'll have access to include wood, mud, thatch and (if he can persuade people to go to a *lot* of effort for it) stone.  Mud can be (and was) baked into bricks, but with shockingly loose tolerances compared to what he'd be used to.  Every piece of wood and stone would be unique, and every piece would require a vast amount of labour to attain.  The real question is not "can Ray build an airport", but "can Ray build a watermill?"

Of course there are things that Ray can contribute to the school of architecture in that period, things like the mathematical underpinnings of arches, buttresses, the engineering behind arch dams and so forth.  But in terms of being able to step onto a building site and take the construction of the pyramids to the next level, his training and experience will serve him poorly.  He'll be better served by his military experience teaching him to adapt to new situations and think on his feet.

Comment: agreed modern architectural practices are really really poor preparation for dealing with worked stone or raw timber. The other big problem he will have is he has no modern tools and he won't know how to use the ones available.

Comment: @John Also, the artisans who built buildings at that time were highly skilled craftsmen. Why would they listen to a gibbering idiot who obviously knew nothing about constructing actual buildings?

Comment: @a4android he doesn't at first, but it's likely that a smart guy can learn the trade relatively quickly.